# An over bracket in under bracket text.

Tags: brackets

Good evening

How to write an over bracket in an under bracket text (the picture below)?

[image]

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably also want a friendly interface:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\textunderbrace}[2]{%
  \ensuremath{\underbrace{\text{#1}}_{\text{#2}}}%
}
\newcommand{\textoverbrace}[2]{%
  \ensuremath{\overbrace{\text{#1}}^{\text{#2}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\textunderbrace{Text \textoverbrace{text}{aaa} text text}{bbb}

\bigskip

\emph{\textunderbrace{Text \textoverbrace{text}{aaa} text text}{bbb}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use `\text{...}` from package `amsmath` for preserve text mode in math environment:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\underbrace{\text{Text }\overbrace{\text{text}}^{\text{aaa}} \text{ text text}}_{\text{bbb}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
in `\itshape`

```
{\itshape
$\underbrace{\text{Text }\overbrace{\text{text}}^{\text{aaa}} \text{ text text}}_{\text{bbb}}$
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can simply nest the commands like

```
$\underbrace{Text \overbrace{text}^{aaa} text text}_{bbb}$
```

Comment: But the text is together. That is wrong. Help me again. :)

Answer (score 1):

You must have the first argument of `\under/\overbrace` in text mode:

```
\[ \underbrace{\emph{Text   $ \overbrace{\text{text}}^{aaa} $ text text}}_{bbb} \]%
```

[image]